# required plugin "org.jetbrains.idea.maven" not installed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I am using Android Studio 3.5.3 , i dont see any option for MAVEN project and i have tried installing couple of plugins after surfing over net. but still no luck.

- I get below error :

***Plugin Error
Problems found loading plugins:
Plugin "Maven Runner" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.idea.maven" not installed.***

I dont see Maven option. only gradel is available

[Android Studio image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHGaH.png)

even here i dont see maven

[Android Studio image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3JYQ.png)

Comment: Did you try this plugin? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7409-maven-runner ?

Comment: Kootli i have tried, issue remains the same "Plugin maven runner depends upon unknown plugin org.jetbrains.idea.maven"